# PHP script doesn't finish after large file download

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP page for a website that will zip files together and allow the user to download it.  The file size of the zip can range anywhere from a couple MB to 100MB.  My PHP script creates the zip file in a temporary directory and then writes the file contents out to the browser.  Once this is finished, the script updates a download counter in a MySQL database and deletes the zip file from the temp directory.

This all works fine until I come across a large zip download that takes longer than 30 seconds.  `max_execution_time` in the php.ini file is set to 30 so this makes sense, but if I try using `set_time_limit(0)` or change `max_execution_time` the same result occurs.  The zip file successfully downloads from the browser with all the correct files inside, but the scripts seems to stop afterwards because the database isn't updated and the temporary zip file on the server isn't deleted.

It's a Linux environment with Apache and PHP 5.2.

This website is hosted on GoDaddy so I'm not sure if they have limitations on changing the time limit a script can execute for but basically I'd like to let this particular script run indefinitely until it completes.

Any thoughts on why I'm not able to set the time limit or any workarounds?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// Don't stop the script if the user 
// closes the browser
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

// Generate random name for ZIP file
$zip_file = "";
$characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

do
{
    $zip_file = "tmp/";

    for ($p = 0; $p < 10; $p++)
        $zip_file .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];

    $zip_file .= ".zip";
} while (file_exists($zip_file));

// Prepare ZIP file
$zip = new ZipArchive();

/* Open and add files to ZIP (this part works fine)
.
.
.
*/

// Close and save ZIP
$zip->close();

// Check browser connection
if (connection_status() == 0)
{
    // Send ZIP
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Download.zip");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

    // Save and then delete file
    //readfile($zip_file);
    if ($file = fopen($zip_file, "r"))
    {
        // Set buffer size
        $buffer_size = 1024 * 8;

        // While we're still transmitting
        // send over bytes!
        while(!feof($file) && (connection_status() == 0))
        {
            print(fread($file, $buffer_size));
            flush();
            usleep(10000); //<!-- Download speed cap
        }

        // Close file descriptor
        fclose($file);  
    }
}

/* Update database download counter if connection_status() == 0
.
.
.
*/

// Delete the file
unlink($zip_file);

?>
```

**UPDATE:** I just tried doing another download from my local web server and bumped up the `usleep` command to 10000 to slow the download time.  Total download time took a little over 1 minute and the database is updated and the file is deleted out of /tmp.  My local environment runs EasyPHP with Apache and PHP 5.3 on a Windows 7 box.  Seems like this could have something to do with GoDaddy.

Also, on both the GoDaddy and local sites, I printed out `max_execution_time` before and after `set_time_limit` is called from my script and the results were 30 and 0 respectively so I'm not sure what's happening on the GoDaddy side of things.

Comment: why you don't generate a temporary file in disk ?

Comment: Why dont you let apache deal with those big downloads. The php script can respond 300 style, to a link that can time out.

Comment: Is your PHP running in safe mode? Not sure about GoDaddy hosting.

Comment: Well, basically I have a transaction ID in a MySQL database that tells PHP what files to pull and put together into a zip download.  I'm trying to track the download count of the transaction in my database and then have it delete the file afterwards.  Also, safe mode does not appear to be on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why the code I'm using above doesn't work on the hosting site, but I found a workaround.  If I use the `register_shutdown_function` call in PHP on the live site, the database is updated correctly and the file is deleted.

Here's the shutdown function code:

```
<?php

$filesize = 0;
$total_bytes_read = 0;
$download_query = "";
$zip_file = "tmp/download.zip";

register_shutdown_function("shutdown");

/* Other code for creating ZIP file and reading it out to the browser
.
.
.
*/

function shutdown()
{
    global $filesize;
    global $total_bytes_read;
    global $zip_file;
    global $download_query;

    // Update the database if file was fully downloaded
    if ($filesize != 0 && $filesize == $total_bytes_read)
    {
        /* Do database update with $download_query
        .
        .
        .
        */
    }

    // Delete the file
    unlink($zip_file);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. maybe the problem in configuration of your HTTP server? What are you using and what is the config?
2. Another variant, when the downloading ends, the connection status may not be equal to 0. So your code in the condition for database update is not evaluated at all.
3. Is there any error logging configured in php.ini? If yes, did you look into the php.error.log, maybe there are some memory leaks and "out of memory" errors.

Comment: It's a GoDaddy account in a Linux environment running Apache.  I turned on error logging so I will check to see if any logs are created.

Comment: I've set error_log in php.ini to a valid filename, but no file is ever generated.  GoDaddy has error logging capabilities but not for economy Linux accounts like mine, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your max_execution_time in your php5.ini and check this with a PHP info page.  Can you provide the sections of your php5.ini and your output from a PHPinfo page?

Comment: I tried changing max_execution_time in php5.ini to 3600 and ran phpinfo() and the output showed 3600, but if the script every took longer than 30 seconds database and server file would never be deleted, even though the download would finish on the browser.  It seems using register_function_shutdown is a better way to handle this.